# Есть ли поддежрка в PHP5  php_Fpm функции mysql_connect?

Tags: apache2, nginx, php, mysql

Я использую *php_fpm* без apache2. php.ini находится в */etc/php5/fpm*

В скрипте появляется ошибка:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect()

Что я сделал

```
sudo php -m
```

Результат:

> mysql mysqli openssl pcntl pcre PDO pdo_mysql

```
sudo php -i | grep mysql
```

Результат:

> /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/mysql.ini, /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/mysqli.ini,/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/pdo_mysql.ini, mysql MYSQL_SOCKET =>/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock MYSQL_INCLUDE => -I/usr/include/mysqlMYSQL_LIBS => -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lmysqlclient_r mysql.allow_local_infile => On => On mysql.allow_persistent => On =>On mysql.connect_timeout => 60 => 60 mysql.default_host => no value =>no value mysql.default_password => no value => no valuemysql.default_port => no value => no value mysql.default_socket =>/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock => /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sockmysql.default_user => no value => no value mysql.max_links =>Unlimited => Unlimited mysql.max_persistent => Unlimited => Unlimitedmysql.trace_mode => Off => Off mysqli MYSQLI_SOCKET =>/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock mysqli.allow_local_infile => On => Onmysqli.allow_persistent => On => On mysqli.default_host => no value =>no value mysqli.default_port => 3306 => 3306 mysqli.default_pw => novalue => no value mysqli.default_socket => /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock=> /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock mysqli.default_user => no value => no value mysqli.max_links => Unlimited => Unlimited mysqli.max_persistent=> Unlimited => Unlimited mysqli.reconnect => Off => Off PDO drivers => mysql, sqlite pdo_mysql pdo_mysql.default_socket => /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock => /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

Comment: Похоже на то, что порт 3306 блокирован фаерволом.

Comment: @Олег Пономарчук, Пожалуйста, используйте кириллицу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А точнее какая версия php? Откуда и как ставили (через менеджер пакетом или руками)?Вообще, как бы:

> Данное расширение устарело, начиная с версии PHP 5.5.0, и будет удалено в будущем. Используйте вместо него MySQLi или PDO_MySQL

Отсюда: http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-connect.php

И сделайте пожалуйста:

> `php -i | grep -C4 mysql`

(в sudo не должно быть необходимости)

И:

> `sudo find /etc /var/lib -name "*mysql*"`.

(Их результаты сюда)